# Python - Creating a Cancel Button for a Countdown Timer

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, timer, countdown

This code is the start of a program simulating a smart toaster. I am trying to make a cancel button for my countdown timer. The timer works fine except for the fact that when the cancel button is pressed, the message 'Timer done' is displayed, but the timer continues. Is there a way I can do this?

```
from tkinter import *
import time

class Window(Frame): #creating window
def __init__(self, master = None): #defining master window
    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.master = master
    self.init_window()

def init_window(self):
    self.master.title("GUI")
    self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1) #allowing size of window to be changed during running of program

    #using a slider instead of a dial as no dial in tkinter
    timerinputDial = Scale(self, from_=0, to=6, tickinterval=1, showvalue=0) 
    timerinputDial.place(x=200, y=20)

#Timer

    def count_down():
        for t in range(((timerinputDial.get())*60), -1, -1): #starts with the value of the input dial
            # format as 2 digit integers, fills with zero to the left
            # divmod() gives minutes, seconds
            sf = "{:02d}:{:02d}".format(*divmod(t, 60))
            #print(sf)
            time_str.set(sf)
            root.update()
            # delay one second
            time.sleep(1)
        if t == 0:
            time_str.set(timer_done) #telling user timer is finished
            timerinputDial.set(0) #setting dial back to 0
            return

    def cancel():
        time_str.set(timer_done) #telling user timer is finished
        timerinputDial.set(0) #setting dial back to 0
        return

    time_str = StringVar()
    timer_done = "Timer done"      

    # creating the time display label, giving it a large font
    # labelling auto-adjusts to the font
    label_font = ('helvetica', 40)
    Label(root, textvariable=time_str, font=label_font, bg='white', 
             fg='blue', relief='raised', bd=3).pack(fill='x', padx=5, pady=5)

    # creating start and stop buttons
    # pack() positions the buttons below the label
    startButton = Button(root, text='Start', command=count_down).pack()
    # stop simply exits root window
    cancelButton = Button(root, text='Cancel', command=cancel).pack()

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")

app = Window(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should include the complete code.

Comment: Ok. I've edited it to add a bit more of the code, so hopefully it makes more sense.

Comment: Does the timer actually continue or restart from 0 but still keep counting?

Comment: We don't need the _complete_ code, we need a [mcve] with proper indentation.

Comment: The count_down function works fine: it counts down from the desired time and stops at zero, but if I press the cancel button during the countdown, the message Timer done appears for one second then the countdown continues from the same point regardless of the cancel function having been run.

Answer (score 0):

I did a simple start/stop timer a while ago.  It just tests an instance variable for starting and stopping.  Note that you should use `after()` instead of `time.sleep()` to avoid a loop stopping everything else from updating.

```
from tkinter import *

class TimerTest():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root=root

        self.is_running=False
        self.count=IntVar()
        self.max_seconds=60  ## quit after this amount of time
        Label(root, textvariable=self.count,
              font=('DejaVuSansMono', 12, "bold"),
              bg="lightyellow").grid(row=1, column=0,
              columnspan=2, sticky="ew")

        Button(root, text="Start", fg="blue", width=15,
                            command=self.startit).grid(row=10,
                            column=0, sticky="nsew")
        Button(root, text="Stop", fg="red", width=15,
                            command=self.stopit).grid(row=10,
                            column=1, sticky="nsew")
        Button(self.root, text="Quit", bg="orange",
                            command=self.root.quit).grid(row=11,
                            column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="nsew")

    def startit(self):
        if not self.is_running:  ## avoid 2 button pushes
            self.is_running=True
            self.increment_counter()

    def increment_counter(self):
        if self.is_running:  ## stopit not called
             c=self.count.get() +1
             self.count.set(c)
             if c < self.max_seconds:
                 self.root.after(1000, self.increment_counter)  ## every second
             else:
                 self.is_running=False
                 Label(root, text="Time Is Up",
                       font=('DejaVuSansMono', 14, "bold"),
                       bg="red").grid(row=5, column=0,
                       columnspan=2, sticky="ew")

    def stopit(self):
        self.is_running = False

root = Tk()
TT=TimerTest(root)
root.mainloop()
```